# What is difference between fault tolerance and fault resilience?

Tags: spring-cloud, spring-cloud-netflix, fault

I am reading Spring Cloud and NetFlix APIs. Many places, I read Fault Tolerance and Fault Resilience keyword.

Please explain the difference.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The *Fault Tolerant* means the ability of an architecture to survive (tolerate) when an environment misbehaves by taking corrective actions, e.g, surviving a server crash or preventing a misbehaving API from bringing down the whole system, etc. The *Fault Resilience* is probably the capacity to recover from these type of scenarios quickly.

After further reading of Netflix blogs and wikis, it seemed the terms *Fault Resilience* and *Fault Tolerant* were used interchangeably.

Answer (score 22):

**Fault tolerance**: User does not see any impact except for some delay during which failover occurs.
**Fault resilience**: Failure is observed in some services. But rest of system continues to function normally.

Comment: definitely more apt than the answer

Answer (score 3):

- ***Fault Tolerance:*** any user of the service does not observe any fault (observing delays is normal).
- ***Fault Resilience:*** a fault may be observed, but only in uncommitted data (like the database may respond with an error to the attempt to commit a transaction, etc.).

[[Reference](https://www.usenix.org/legacy/publications/library/proceedings/usenix04/tech/sigs/full_papers/bottomley/bottomley_html/node21.html)]